# How to find the structure factor for the BCC lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

[image]

why is the value of structure factor zero when value of exponential is -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $S=f(1+e^{x})$. If $e^{x}=-1$ then $S=f(1+(-1))=0$

Comment: thank you, I made a mistake in writing the expression